# Does the ADDITIONAL GUNS option in Jagged Alliance 2: Unfinished Business effect the difficulty of the game?

Tags: jagged-alliance

In Jagged-Alliance-2: Unfinished Business there is an option to add additional guns to the game. Does this increase the difficulty of the game (Say by giving your opponents better weapons while leaving your starting weapons the same), decrease it (Give you better starting weapons, give you more options latter on) or not really effect the difficulty of the game?

Comment: isn't a similar option in vanilla JA2?

Comment: I have no idea: I only own JG2:UB. Steam had them on sale, and I figured the most recent one would be the best, since I was sick of X-COM's very dated UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I provide this answer although I never played UB, but am pretty sure that the option has the same effect as in standard JA2.

Jagged Alliance has some sort of algorithm that gives your opponents weapons to fit the sectors difficulty. The option has no effect on how good certain weapons are, but the games table to choose a weapon from is just bigger.

I did not want to write the above stuff without [confirmation](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/197667-jagged-alliance-2/47518748), so here it goes:

> but just for the record, tons of guns tends to make ammo problems worse, not better. It doesn't mean you get more equipment; it means you get a greater variety of equipment. With tons of guns, you'll find guns and ammo types that just aren't available in normal mode. (The idea was to provide a mode with a reduced weapon's set for anyone who was feeling overwhelmed by the sheer size of the JA2 arsenal.) As a result, while you're getting just as much stuff, it's divided among a far more diverse array of weapons and ammo, forcing you to diversify your team to a far greater extent or risk bleeding yourself dry of a critical ammo type.

Comment: Completely correct, either for JA2 or JA:UB. *Tons of guns* setting means opposition will ***NOT** wield an unified armament*, which in turn leads to ammunition diversity in the *loot*. Effect on game difficulty highly depends on ***player's** armament diversity*, in average difficulty increases.